# Tumbleweed badge received after two months. Shouldn't it be after one week?

Tags: support, badges

I just received the Tumbleweed after two months while its description says:

> Asked a question with zero score, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week.

I suppose that is probably is due to the fact that Salesforce.SE isn't a community as big as SO or other big ones. In fact is much more difficult to get this badge on these communities.

If this is the case, shouldn't be the description updated accordingly on the base of the community?

If this is not the case, is it a bug?

Comment: Probably the description is accurate, and they just have a job which runs monthly or similar to check which posts qualify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were actually awarded the badge a while ago when the question was first eligible per the criteria. On May 17, you had an account merge take place and lost the badge through the merge process (which is common and expected). The system then re-awarded you *the same badge you already had* because you were still eligible for it. You received six such badges that day.